# Two ips rotating each time an email is sent - iptables

Tags: email, iptables, smtp, ip, email-server

I have two ips attempting to rotate each time an email is sent from server. The following commands say they are configured:

```
sudo ifup venet0:0
ifup: interface venet0:0 already configured
sudo ifup venet0:1
ifup: interface venet0:1 already configured
```

Then I entered the following commands into iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -o venet0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 1 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source xxx.xxx.xxx.111
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -o venet0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source xxx.xxx.xxx.222
```

But each email still says it is from xxx.xxx.xxx.111 which is the original ip of the server. Is there another step that I'm missing?

Comment: Are the packet counts on both rules incrementing?

Comment: The victims will probably just update their spamfilters to include your whole ip-range

Comment: Your rule mentions `--dport 80` and it should be port 25 for the destination if you are sending email